# Как обновить таблицу не закрывая окно редактирования Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo

Имеется таблица с данными. Я использую "Popup editing" и отдельный шаблон для этого окна.

```
        editable: {
        mode: "popup",
        window : {
            resizable: true,
            animation: false,
            modal: false
        },
        template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
        },
```

Хочу сделать обновление таблицы в то время, когда пользователь работает с окном редактирования, но оно закрывается, когда я делаю это.

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

Как обновить таблицу не закрывая окно?

```
     setInterval(function(){
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

        grid.bind("dataBinding",function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
        });

        grid.dataSource.read();
        grid.refresh();
    }, 60000);
```

Скрин ошибки:
http://postimg.org/image/gq8ioefyl/

Answer (score 1):

Обновляется грид следующим образом:

```
$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

Что бы окошко не закрывалось нужно сделать превент:

```
grid.bind("dataBinding",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Ссылка на обсуждение данного вопроса на сайте телерика:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-prevent-editor-from-closing-

Comment: окно все равно закрывается.

Comment: Спс, работает. Только теперь появилась ошибка при закрытии: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

Comment: Возможно вы ошиблись в написании имени идентификатора.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что Вы имеете в виду. Я добавил код как я сделал. Скорее всего причина ошибки  - e.preventDefault();

Comment: Добавил скрин ошибки после закрытия окна.

Comment: биндить желательно 1 раз. Касательно ошибки, то тут нужно смотреть полностью исходник.